# How can i make the following function more efficient?

Tags: scala, performance

Here is a function which makes a map from given array. Where key is the integer number and the value is the frequency of this number in the given array. 
I need to find the key which has the maximum frequency. If two key has the same frequency then i need to take the key which is smaller.

**that's what i have written:**

```
def findMinKeyWithMaxFrequency(arr: List[Int]): Int = {
    val ansMap:scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Map()

    arr.map(elem=> ansMap+=(elem->arr.count(p=>elem==p)))
    ansMap.filter(_._2==ansMap.values.max).keys.min
  }
val arr = List(1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4)

val ans=findMinKeyWithMaxFrequency(arr) // output:3
```

How can i make it more efficient, it is giving me the right answer but i don't think it's the most efficient way to solve the problem.

In the given example the frequency of 3 and 4 is 3 so the answer should be 3 as 3 is smaller than 4.

***Edit 1:***

That's what i have done to make it bit efficient. Which is converting arr into Set as we need to find frequency for the unique elements only.

```
def findMinKeyWithMaxFrequency(arr: List[Int]): Int = {
    val ansMap=arr.toSet.map{ e: Int =>(e,arr.count(x=>x==e))}.toMap

    ansMap.filter(_._2==ansMap.values.max).keys.min
  }
```

Can it be more efficient? Is it the most functional way of writing the solution for the given problem.

Comment: Is your input expected not to be empty?

Comment: @XavierGuihot  input will be non empty always.

Comment: What is a "frequency" of an element in a set? Isn't it always exactly `1`, for every element that is in the set? I don't understand what you're asking. Also, how big is the array, and would it help to parallelize the computation? ...and what do you mean by "functional". On such tiny not-parallelized computations that take place in a single function in the memory of a single computer, being "functional" doesn't buy you much, it could be that a simple `while` loop does the same job faster.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin what is the frequency of an element in the given array not in the set. I have clearly mentioned in the question that we need to find the max frequency of the element in given array. If two or more elements has the same frequency which is equal to max frequency then we need to take the element which is smaller. And the size of the array can go up to 10^8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def findMinKeyWithMaxFrequency(arr: List[Int]): Int =
  arr.groupBy(identity).toSeq.maxBy(p => (p._2.length,-p._1))._1
```

Use `groupBy()` to get an effective count for each element then, after flattening to a sequence of tuples, code the required rules to determine the maximum.

Comment: Thank you!! That’s what I was looking for.

Comment: why do we have -p,_1?? we can't we do   arr.groupBy(identity).toSeq.maxBy(p => p._2.length)._1

Comment: The `groupBy` transformation generates a Map of Int-type keys and List-type values.  `p => (p._2.length, -p._1)` instructs `maxBy` to use the ordering of the list size of the Map key (in ascending order) followed by the corresponding integer Map value (in descending order because of the `-` negation) to arrive at the maximum (k, v) tuple.

Comment: @RamanMishra; When tuples are compared, if the 1st elements are equal then the 2nd element is used as the tiebreaker. By negating the value just for comparison purposes the minimum will be chosen.